# Postgresql query / Group by and sum

Tags: json, postgresql

Just joined the group yesterday, and have already received great advice from the community.   I have another scenario I need a bit of a push with.  The advice I received yesterday resolved my first issue, but I have a 2nd scenario I would like to try implementing.

I have the following Postgresql query that converts a "size" value from a json column type from bytes to MB:

```
SELECT c.name AS customer, i.customer_id, i.captured_at, i.name AS image, 
i.raw_upload_complete
, pg_size_pretty((i.manifest ->> 'size')::numeric) AS image_size
FROM   public.images i
JOIN   public.customers c ON c.id = i.customer_id
WHERE  i.raw_upload_complete = 'true' AND captured_at > date_trunc('day', now()) - 
interval '2 months'
ORDER  BY customer ASC
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
Customer   Customer ID  captured_at  image        raw_upload_complete   image_size
Customer 1  250         2022-05-09   Ventures Pit       TRUE              4044 MB
Customer 1  250         2022-06-01   Ventures Pit       TRUE              500 MB
Customer 2  85          2022-04-18   Devault Quarry     TRUE              672 MB
Customer 2  85          2022-05-02   Talmage Quarry     TRUE              3876 MB
```

The query works great, however, what I would like to do is group the result set by Customer, and SUM the image_size for each customer.  So in the above example, I'd like to have the customers grouped as they are, and reflect customer 1 has a total image size of 4544 MB, and Customer 2 has a total image size of 4548 MB.  Ideally I'd like each customer summarized on one line, or in some kind of high-level rolled-up fashion.

I mentioned in my first post I am fairly new at SQL so the solutions could be obvious, but I've been struggling with this one.  I've tried the crosstab function to no avail, but I'm not sure if there is a better option.  The thing that seems to have been giving me issues is that the image_size column that was created comes out as TEXT, not numeric, which has been causing issues.  I have been using Google Data Studio and thought simply changing the data type would help, but even though it would let me change it to a number, it was still being recognized as a text field.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to work this backwards.  First, let's write a query that gets the total image size by customer

```sql
select c.id, pg_size_pretty(sum((i.manifest ->> 'size')::numeric)) as total
from images i
join customers c on i.customer_id = c.id
where [snippped]
group by c.id
```

Note that you want to do the `sum()`, and **then** apply `pg_size_pretty`.  That's because the results of `pg_size_pretty()` will have the "MB", "GB" stuff inside, so it's actually text and not a number anymore.

Now we can use that query as a CTE to get the result you want

```sql
with total_size as (
  select c.id, pg_size_pretty(sum((i.manifest ->> 'size')::numeric)) as total
  from images i
  join customers c on i.customer_id = c.id
  where [snippped]
  group by c.id
) as total

SELECT c.name AS customer, i.customer_id, i.captured_at, i.name AS image, 
i.raw_upload_complete
, total_size.total
FROM   public.images i
JOIN   public.customers c ON c.id = i.customer_id
JOIN   total_size on c.id = total_size.id
WHERE  i.raw_upload_complete = 'true' AND captured_at > date_trunc('day', now()) - 
interval '2 months'
ORDER  BY customer ASC
```

So if you look carefully, you'll see that we have the additional join to the "total" CTE, and that the SELECT clause uses the "total" value from the CTE.

The reason why you have to do this in two steps is that your desired result mixes detailed image data (e.g. "captured_at") with summary image data (the total size).  That kind of mixing trips up a lot of people who are learning SQL.

Comment: Hey Chris - thank you very much for such a great, detailed response.  I really appreciate it.  I do have a couple of follow up questions if I may.  After playing with the query a bit, the only way I was able to get it to run was if I removed "as total" from line 7 above due to an error - "syntax error at or near "as", on Line 6 (it's line 6 in my editor)."  Also, it appears the math may be slightly off.  For example, when I take customer 1 as an example, their image sizes add up to 34856MB, which is 34.8GB.  The total size from the query above for customer 1 is 371GB.

Comment: Here are the values for customer 1: 1229 MB
2052 MB
4399 MB
4601 MB
4643 MB
4404 MB
4422 MB
2046 MB
1215 MB
4636 MB
1209 MB

Comment: hello again.  I believe I may have resolved my issue by removing the "as total" and also, the math seems to work after I made a few changes to the WHERE statements.  I was not using it correctly in the first query you provided to come up with the total size.  My changes also have taken the query from almost 3 minutes down to about 3 seconds.  Thanks again!

Comment: ahh, you are correct .. "as total" is not valid SQL syntax for CTEs...we use "with total ..."